# Biggest Nested Contour OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, contour

Im struggling at finding the biggest nested contour in my hierarchy.
Can someone help?
I just need the biggest shape of the contours and need to check if the second-biggest contour is a child of it.
Here is my code:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closing, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    sorted_contour = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

    bigcontour1 = sorted_contour[0]
    bigcontour2 = sorted_contour[1]
```

Comment: Define "biggest". By what measure -- area or perimeter or what?

Answer (score 3):

Why not just search for the largest external contour in Python/OpenCV?

```
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh2, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
```

Comment: I would recommend using `cv2.RETR_TREE` instead of `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` since the largest contour could be a nested child contour

Comment: @Nathancy.  Yes, thanks. I overlooked that thinking inner contours would be smaller since they were inside. But you are absolutely correct.